# Update Custom Options via Querystring from external site - Magento

Tags: magento

We have an external site that has our product with a few options, and we want to pass that data from that site to the product page of the store so that the customer can update more attributes and add an image.  I know there is a way to add it directly to the cart but we want them to stop at the product page first to answer more questions before adding to cart.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an observer to capture the event before the add to cart, and grab the values needed and set them on the product option of the PDP.

More details on the observer pattern can be found here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: Not sure how this is going to work. We are using custom options on our products.  Just looking for a simple way to get the options from an external site to the product page with those values in magento.